# SQL statement to perform incremental updates based upon conditon

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a sql update statement that will look for a company name sort their accompanying materials alphabetically then update another field in the table in increments of ten after setting a seed value.

The pseudocode sql I envision is something like this

```
@orderincrement = 100
Update Materials 
Set Order = @orderincrenment + 10
where CompanyName = 'ThisCompany'
order by materials
```

Current Table Example:
[image: Current Table]

What I want it to look like after:
[image]
It has been a while since I have done sql scripting.
Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Pleaseprovide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by comapnyname order by materials) as seqnum
      from materials m
     )
update toupdate
    set order = @orderincrement + 10 * seqnum
    where companyname = ?;
```

I am guessing a bit on the actual arithmetic that you want, but whether you want to start at 10 in increments of 100 or at 100 in increments of 10, most of the query is the same.

Comment: so to seed the '@orderincrement' would it be as simple as @orderincrement = 100?

Comment: @Sean . . . That would be the starting value.  The `10` is the incremental value (which seems strange, but what you want isn't totally clear).

Comment: added example of before and after in original post, I am going to try what you have given me and see what I get.